# What is this pronoun "who" referring to?

Tags: word-usage, pronouns

> A 15-page document is a summary of an FBI interview done in 2015 with a man
> **who** had frequent contact with Saudi nationals in the U.S. **who** supported the first hijackers to arrive in the country before the attacks.

I know the first "who" is referring to "a man" preceding it. How about the second "who"?

Comment: This sentence is from Yahoo News

Comment: Please edit your question (do not create a new comment) to include a link to the source of the quote.

Comment: Yes, Please place your your source in the question. .a single line after the quote (italic font to separate it from the quote) Example *source: joesrockingnews.com*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you say, the first **who** refers to the noun immediately before it: **a man**.

In general you go to the first noun immediately preceding the pronoun and that will be the antecedent. There are exceptions, but this is not one of them: the second **who** refers to **Saudi nationals [in the U.S.]**.